# Cannot compare different days

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

My code looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd 
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

df = pd.DataFrame ({
    'User':['Mcafee','John','Albert'],
    'LastOnline':['4/1/2020  1:41:17', '3/5/2020  09:1:23', '1/1/2020  06:51:1'],
    'Status':["NaN","NaN","NaN"]
    })

df['LastOnline'] = pd.to_datetime(df['LastOnline'],format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
date = '04/03/2020'
datetime_object = datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y')

diff = datetime_object - df['LastOnline']
seven_days  = timedelta(days=7)
thirty_days = timedelta(days=30)

if diff <= seven_days:
    df['Status'] = "7 days ago"
elif (diff > seven_days) & (diff <= thirty_days):
    df['Status'] = "30 days ago"
else:
    df['Status'] = "disable it"

print(df)
```

Initial df is:

```
     User          LastOnline Status
0  Mcafee 2020-04-01 01:41:17    NaN
1    John 2020-03-05 09:01:23    NaN
2  Albert 2020-01-01 06:51:01    NaN
```

What I would like to achieve is to change the **Status** column based on a simple logic. If **df['LastOnline']** is within 7 days then change **df['Status']** to *7days ago* and so on as described in the if statements above. Here is the right output.

```
     User          LastOnline Status
0  Mcafee 2020-04-01 01:41:17    7 days ago
1    John 2020-03-05 09:01:23    30 days ago
2  Albert 2020-01-01 06:51:01    disable it
```

But I get this error:

```
  File ".\test.py", line 21, in <module>
    if diff <= seven_days:
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1555, in __nonzero__
    self.__class__.__name__
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

What the comparison is not working? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid loops and use [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) with [`series.dt.days`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html) after getting difference of `datetime_object` with the existing series (`'LastOnline'`):

```
days_diff = (datetime_object - df['LastOnline']).dt.days
#define the conditions
c1,c2 = days_diff.le(7) , days_diff.gt(7) & days_diff.le(30)

df['Status'] = np.select([c1,c2],['7 days ago','30 days ago'],'disable it')
print(df)
```

---

```
     User          LastOnline       Status
0  Mcafee 2020-04-01 01:41:17   7 days ago
1    John 2020-03-05 09:01:23  30 days ago
2  Albert 2020-01-01 06:51:01   disable it
```

Comment: Thank you very much!